# How to detect whether operating system is server 2008 r2, 2008 sp etc

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am using caption property of win32_operatingsystem management object.  (see below)

Is this reliable? Note that i am interested in en-US. So locale does not matter.

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.EXCH2010> gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem  -ComputerName name | select caption

caption
-------
Microsoftr Windows Serverr 2008 Enterprise


PS C:\Users\administrator.EXCH2010> gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem  |  select caption

caption
-------
Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
```

-Dreamer!

Answer (score 1):

Sure is reliable!! I've used just some day ago to retrieve all versions (ent/std/R2) in a multi domain environment for renew conctract assurance with microsoft!

Go with it!